# List the elements of $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$ and write its operation table (the notation is additive).

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

$\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3  = \{(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2)\}.$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
+ & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2)\\
\hline
(0, 0) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) \\
(0, 1) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 3) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 3) \\
(0, 2)  & (0, 2) & (0, 3) & (0, 4) & (1, 2) & (1, 3) & (1, 4) \\
(1, 0) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (2, 0) & (2, 1) & (2, 3) \\
(1, 1)  & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 3) & (2, 1) & (2, 2) & (2, 3) \\
(1, 2)  & (1, 2) & (1, 3) & (1, 4) & (2, 2) & (2, 3) & (2, 4) \\
\end{array}
$$

Please, check my work.

Comment: While your table is, in a certain sense, completely correct, you are likely to get marked down for claiming that $(1,2)+(1,2) = (2,4)$ rather than $(0,1)$, because it suggests that you don't understand what you are doing.

Comment: @ MJD, why is $(1, 2) + (1, 2) = (0, 1)?$

Comment: What is $2+2$ in $\mathbb Z_3$? What is $1+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2$? @Marko

Comment: @  Thomas Andrews, $1 + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_2$, and $2 + 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb Z_3$ ?

Comment: @ Thomas Andrews, $0 = 3$ in $Z_3$, so $2 + 2 = 1$ in $Z_3.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb Z_3=\{0,1,2\}$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
+ & 0  &1 & 2\\
\hline
0 & 0  &1 & 2\\
1 & 1  &2 & 0\\
2 & 2  &0 & 1\\
\end{array}
$\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_2=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(1,1),(1,2)\}$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
+ & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2)\\
\hline
(0, 0) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) \\
(0, 1) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) \\
(0, 2)  & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) \\
(1, 0) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) \\
(1, 1)  & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) \\
(1, 2)  & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) \\
\end{array}
As a general idea, when you write the table group of an operation, each element should appear only once on each column and row. Of course that in $\mathbb{Z}_3, 4=1$ because $4\equiv 1\pmod 3$ but is preferable to keep the same notation for an element.

Edit: The operation on $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3$ is defined as follows: for $(a,b),(c,d)\in \mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_3$, i.e. $a,c\in\mathbb Z_2, b,d\in\mathbb Z_3, (a,b)+(c,d)=(a+c,b+d)$. The idea when you write these elements is to keep the same writing always.

When you make a sum in $\mathbb Z_n$, the elements are classes of equivalence (in $\mathbb{Z}_n, 0=n=2n=\dots; 1=n+1=2n+1=\dots ; 2=n+2=2n+2=\dots$ and so on - basically whenever an n appears it is made $0$)and you choose to work with the smallest representants $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, so if you have that for example $x+y=n+k$, you shall write $x+y=k$.

Comment: @ Iulia, why is $(1, 2) + (1, 2) = (0, 1)$?

Comment: @mako, I have made an edit. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Your addition table is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm terribly sorry to mention it, but I fear this table may be wrong. $\Bbb{Z}_2$ and $\Bbb{Z}_3$ are groups. Therefore, $\Bbb{Z}_2$ X $\Bbb{Z}_3$ is a group.  All such groups are closed, aint they? That is, if a,b is in the set, then a+b (if the operation is additive) is also in the set. Since, for instance, (2,1) is not in the set $\Bbb{Z}_2$ X $\Bbb{Z}_3$ how can it be in the operation table? It seems we would have to restrict the LHS of each pair to modulo 2, so 2 would never appear, would it?

Comment: This amounts to a correct comment,

Comment: As MJD's comment shows, the OP's table is technically correct, since (eg) $1 \equiv 4 \pmod 3$, but it is better to reduce the terms of the tuple by the appropriate modulus.

Comment: @PM2Ring points out the interesting phenomenon that the (moral, not mathematical) correctness of the original answer depends on the poster's knowledge.  An experienced mathematician providing this answer might be doing so to demonstrate that $4$ is just as good an answer to a calculation modulo $3$ as $1$; an inexperienced mathematician has probably missed the point of modular arithmetic.  (On the other hand, it is very important that no-one think that $\mathbb Z_2$ (really $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$) equals $\{0, 1\}$, a subset of $\mathbb Z$; actually it is a set of congruence classes.)

Answer (score 0):

As Omne Bonum mentions, adding two members of a group *must* yield a member of the group. Using the notation given in the question, in $\mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_3$, 
$$(a, b) + (c, d) = ((a+c)\mod 2, \ (b+d)\mod 3)$$

Here is the corrected addition table.

$$\begin{array}{c|lcr}
+ & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2)\\
\hline
(0, 0) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) \\
(0, 1) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) \\
(0, 2) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) \\
(1, 0) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) \\
(1, 1) & (1, 1) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (0, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) \\
(1, 2) & (1, 2) & (1, 0) & (1, 1) & (0, 2) & (0, 0) & (0, 1) \\
\end{array}$$